# Sorting data in Access database where the column has numbers and letters

Tags: sql, ms-access

Please help me because I have been unable to get this right.

What is the access SQL to select this column(columnA) so that it returns a resultset with distinct values sorted first according to numbers and then to letters.

Here is the columns values: {10A,9C,12D,11G,9B,10C,9R,8T}

I have tried 'Select distinct ColumnA from tblClass order by 1'
but it returns {10A,10C,11G,12D,8T,9B,9C,9R} which is not what I want.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there always one letter in the end?

Comment: Suggestion: a) store as fixed width text (i.e. `NCHAR(n)` data type) and left-pad with zeros to fill; b) remove leading zeros in the display (front end, report, etc).

Comment: If you have to consider subparts of a data field independently, that's a chief indication of a normalization error, since it shows that you're storing two pieces of data in a single field.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Val() function for this.  From the help topic: "*The Val function stops reading the string at the first character it can't recognize as part of a number*"

Val(10A) will give you 10, Val(9C) will give you 9, and so on.  So in your query, order by Val(ColumnA) first, then ColumnA.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Val([ColumnA]) AS number_part, ColumnA
FROM tblClass
ORDER BY Val([ColumnA]), ColumnA;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ColumnA
FROM tblClass 
ORDER BY CInt(LEFT(ColumnA,len(ColumnA)-1)), RIGHT(ColumnA,1);
```

If there last character is a letter and the others are a number.

Answer (score 0):

Your data type is a string so it's sorting correctly, to get the result you want you're going to have to split your values into numeric and alphabetic parts and then sort first on the numeric then the alphabetic. Not being an Access programmer I can't help you with exactly how you're going to do that.

Answer (score 0):

order by 1?

Don't you mean order by ColumnA?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ColumnA
FROM tblClass
ORDER BY ColumnA
```

Comment: `ORDER BY 1` is shorthand for order by the first column.

Comment: hmm... you would think I would know that.

Comment: It's an absolutely terrible thing to do to yourself though. Using ordinal position that is. Good luck when someone changes your table.

Comment: I mean by the first column returned in your query, not the first column in the table. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: Ah, well I suppose that does make more sense, still seems like a bad idea just in that it isn't very clear. Learn something new every day. Thanks cularis.

Comment: Using the column index does come in quite handy with UNION SELECTs because the field you're sorting on may have a completely different name in the various source tables. It might be just as confusing to use a field name that's not present in all the tables as it would be to use the column index.

Comment: I've never had to type them twice because I use the QBE to write most of my SQL...

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem and used a dummie workaround:

changing a list of {10A,10C,11G,12D,8T,9B,9C,9R}

into {10A,10C,11G,12D,08T,09B,09C,09R} by adding the 0 before each <10 number.

now all items are the same length and access will sort correctly into {08T, 09B, 09C, 09R, 10A, 10C, 11G, 12D}
.

To achieve this, I copied this column into excel column A and used IF(LEN(A2)<3, concatenate("0", A2))

Comment: Be more informative as others can easily understand

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it